# Finder Smart Folder - Seeing file size in OS X 10.5

Tags: macos, finder

I've created a smart folder showing the large files on my computer.

The resulting view lists the file name and 2 other fields - don't have it in front of me.

It does not show the file size.  The only way to see it is to click on get info - not really what I want.  I'd like a column which displays it, so I can sort it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list view, or list part of cover-flow, in a smart folder will show the name, kind, and last opened date. It does not seem to allow you to change these columns, and there are no view options (command-j) for a smart folder.

It might console you slightly to see that if you view the files in icon view, certain types, like dmgs will show their size in blue, and movies will show their running-time.

I would recommend just getting a listing with sizes from the terminal with `ls` or `du` but I'm not certain that the smart-folders look like directories on the unix side of things.

Comment: I've been looking at some Finder replacements.  Finder makes me miss Windows.